# Why custom Preference has larger text size?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

I have a custom preference for showing icon with title and summary. But I don't know why its title has a larger text size compared to the normal preferences (built in one). Here are the source and layout xml of my custom preference. If you need more info, please let me know. Thank You.

```
public class IconPreferenceScreen extends Preference {

    public Drawable mIcon;
    private ImageView mImageView;

    public IconPreferenceScreen(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.preferenceStyle);
    }

    public IconPreferenceScreen(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setLayoutResource(R.layout.preference_icon);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.IconPreferenceScreen, defStyle, android.R.attr.preferenceStyle);
        mIcon = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.IconPreferenceScreen_iconPref);
        a.recycle();
    }

    public IconPreferenceScreen(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
        setLayoutResource(R.layout.preference_icon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindView(View view) {
        super.onBindView(view);
        mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        if (mImageView != null && mIcon != null) {
            mImageView.setImageDrawable(mIcon);
        }
    }

    public void setIcon(Drawable icon) {
        if (mImageView != null && icon != null) {
            mImageView.setImageDrawable(icon);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
        View layout= super.onCreateView(parent);
        layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return layout;
    }    
}
```

Layout file here

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+android:id/widget_frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal" />

        <TextView android:id="@+android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:maxLines="2" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is likely that your title uses `android:attr/textAppearanceLarge`. Digging through the Android source code, the [`preferences_child.xml`](http://androidxref.com/source/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/preference_child.xml) resource instead uses `?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium`.

Comment: Oh, I have a look of preferences.xml before instead of preferences_child.xml. How do you find this?

Comment: I just use that website. Anything that is "core" to Android will be found in `frameworks/base/core/`, anything that's in an app will be in `packages/apps/`. It's worth having a look around on that website, you often find some very good stuff!